# How can I declare custom pins when using with ESP8266 in MPU9250 library

Tags: esp8266, i2c, imu

I want to declare SCL and SCK pins like   `Wire.begin(sda_pin, scl_pin);` to use with ESP8266 to integrate a MPU 9250/6500 sensor.
I can't figure out a way to declare that in this code exaample provided by https://github.com/bolderflight/MPU9250

in the example of the above it has just passed as **Wire** to and created object like `MPU9250 IMU(Wire,0x68);` which was meant to be used with UNO boards(as I think)

And in any case if any of you have seen a library that can be used with the ESP8266 for the MPU 9250/6500 point me on that direction please (I'm trying to get the roll, pitch, yaw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Wire.pins(sda, scl);` before `IMU.begin();`.
`IMU.begin()` then calls `Wire.begin()` without parameters.